# position div over another to keep it same on all devices

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a div position a little above my other divs. The plate and cake-lower div are exactly in middle of the page so they are fine, but the cake-top div needs to be 40-50px above the middle of the page. I am able to achieve this by changing the margin attribute, but this is only for my device. Which properties should be modified in the css to make this design responsive across all screen sizes?

```css
body{
        background-color: plum;
    }
    .container{
        border: 2px solid black;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .cake-lower{
        border: 1px solid #654321;
        background-color : #654321;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        border-top-left-radius: 20%;
        border-top-right-radius: 20%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    }
    .cake-top{
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        background:#9f6934;
        border-radius: 50px / 25px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 70px;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
    
    }
    .plate{
        width: 250px;
        height: 125px;
        background:white;
        border-radius: 125px / 64px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="container">
            <div class="plate" ></div>
            <div class="cake-lower"></div>
            <div class="cake-top" ></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It would be easier for you to move the container across the screen, set its `position: relative` and then you can position the inner elements relatively to the container, instead of relatively to the entire document

Comment: I don't see the problem in the snippet in your question. Is there a particular device that the problem is with? However I agree with @Itay - I was going to suggest positioning the cake elements within its own container, and then position that container where you want on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **relying on the browser to calculate the positions** of each of the elements, but when the calculations result in decimals (e.g. `2.5px`), different browsers can handle this differently.

The best way to guarantee the elements will all appear *exactly* where you want them is to specify the exact position where you want them, e.g. `top: 10px; left: 74px`.

You should use a container just for the cake elements to do this. This acts as a single unit and can be positioned wherever you wish, and if it moves the cake elements are still all in the correct positions *within* that container.

**In the example below,** I've created a `full-cake` container, and all of the cake elements are placed at exact pixel positions relative to it:

```css
body {
  background-color: plum;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.full-cake {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 125px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}

.cake-lower {
  border: 1px solid #654321;
  background-color: #654321;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 74px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-left-radius: 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
}

.cake-top {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #9f6934;
  border-radius: 50px / 25px;
  left: 74px;
  top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}

.plate {
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 125px / 64px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-cake">
    <div class="plate"></div>
    <div class="cake-lower"></div>
    <div class="cake-top"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This can also be done in the main container i guess. Why use a separate cake container in the main container?

Comment: @UneezehHabib Because it makes them act as a single unit. Move it and you move all the elements without needing to make any changes to them. You *could* do it on the main container, but the if you want to move the cake, you have to change the position of every one of the elements individually. If you were using media queries, this could be even bigger task. As I mentioned in my answer, by using a container for all elements you only have to position that container and everything else will stay in the correct position as they are relative to that container.

Comment: Yes actually now that I looked into it and ran it on different browsers, I understand your point better. The calc() provides a temporary solution in this case but this is a more generic one. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

### Tools you can use

Hello! I think you're looking for is a combination of:

- [the calc() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), and
- [viewport units](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/vi/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

The calc() function lets you combine lengths that use different units for calculation in the browser.

The `vh` unit is a responsive unit that is based on the height of your viewport. `1vh` is 1% of the visible height of your page. You can also do interesting things with division and multiplication that also accounts for `vw` units.

### Applied to your example

Though you will need to change the specific calculation, I have made the follow alteration to your code for `.cake-top`:

```
bottom: calc(70px + 5vh);
```

This shows you how to combine your existing `70px` value to also account for the viewport height. As I mentioned, you might need to also account for viewport width - have a play around!

```css
body{
        background-color: plum;
    }
    .container{
        border: 2px solid black;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .cake-lower{
        border: 1px solid #654321;
        background-color : #654321;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        border-top-left-radius: 20%;
        border-top-right-radius: 20%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    }
    .cake-top{
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        background:#9f6934;
        border-radius: 50px / 25px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: calc(70px + 5vh);
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
    
    }
    .plate{
        width: 250px;
        height: 125px;
        background:white;
        border-radius: 125px / 64px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="plate" ></div>
            <div class="cake-lower"></div>
            <div class="cake-top" ></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: A great explanation! Bless you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: plum;
        }
        .container{
            border: 0.3vw solid black;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .cake-lower{
            border: 0.3vw solid #654321;
            background-color : #654321;
            height: 23vh;
            width: 15vw;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            border-top-left-radius: 20%;
            border-top-right-radius: 20%;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
        }
        .cake-top{
            width: 15vw;
            height: 11vh;
            background:#9f6934;
            border-radius: 25vw / 20vh;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 16vh;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;

        }
        .plate{
            width: 40vw;
            height: 30vh;
            background:white;
            border-radius: 25vw / 20vh;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
        }

        @-ms-viewport{
          width: device-width;
      }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="plate" ></div>
    <div class="cake-lower"></div>
    <div class="cake-top" ></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inserted `<meta>` to control view-port. Replaced pixel values with corresponding values based on view-port height and width.

Comment: You haven't put that in your code. So I mention it. After-all it is useless unless we not use units based on view-port width and height. Hope my code solved your problem.